# Unresolved external symbol errors when using FLTK 1.3.9 with Visual Studio Community 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg, unresolved-external, fltk

We are using Visual Studio 2022 and I am getting these errors:

```
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl Fl::wait(void)" (?wait@Fl@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Win1::wait_for_button(void)" (?wait_for_button@Win1@@QAEHXZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Fl::redraw(void)" (?redraw@Fl@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall Win1::wait_for_button(void)" (?wait_for_button@Win1@@QAEHXZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::flush(void)" (?flush@Fl_Window@@MAEXXZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::flush(void)" (?flush@Fl_Window@@MAEXXZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Fl_Window::~Fl_Window(void)" (??1Fl_Window@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::~Window(void)" (??1Window@Graph_lib@@UAE@XZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Fl_Window::~Fl_Window(void)" (??1Fl_Window@@UAE@XZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Fl_Window::handle(int)" (?handle@Fl_Window@@UAEHH@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Fl_Window::handle(int)" (?handle@Fl_Window@@UAEHH@Z)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::resize(int,int,int,int)" (?resize@Fl_Window@@UAEXHHHH@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::resize(int,int,int,int)" (?resize@Fl_Window@@UAEXHHHH@Z)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::show(void)" (?show@Fl_Window@@UAEXXZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::show(void)" (?show@Fl_Window@@UAEXXZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::hide(void)" (?hide@Fl_Window@@UAEXXZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::hide(void)" (?hide@Fl_Window@@UAEXXZ)
1>gin_v_2.1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Fl_Graphics_Driver * fl_graphics_driver" (?fl_graphics_driver@@3PAVFl_Graphics_Driver@@A)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Fl_Graphics_Driver * fl_graphics_driver" (?fl_graphics_driver@@3PAVFl_Graphics_Driver@@A)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall Fl_Image::draw_empty(int,int)" (?draw_empty@Fl_Image@@IAEXHH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Bad_image::draw(int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?draw@Bad_image@Graph_lib@@UAEXHHHHHH@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Image::Fl_Image(int,int,int)" (??0Fl_Image@@QAE@HHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Bad_image::Bad_image(int,int)" (??0Bad_image@Graph_lib@@QAE@HH@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Fl_Image::~Fl_Image(void)" (??1Fl_Image@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Graph_lib::Bad_image::~Bad_image(void)" (??1Bad_image@Graph_lib@@UAE@XZ)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class Fl_Image * __thiscall Fl_Image::copy(int,int)" (?copy@Fl_Image@@UAEPAV1@HH@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Image::color_average(unsigned int,float)" (?color_average@Fl_Image@@UAEXIM@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Image::desaturate(void)" (?desaturate@Fl_Image@@UAEXXZ)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Image::label(class Fl_Widget *)" (?label@Fl_Image@@UAEXPAVFl_Widget@@@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Image::label(struct Fl_Menu_Item *)" (?label@Fl_Image@@UAEXPAUFl_Menu_Item@@@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Image::uncache(void)" (?uncache@Fl_Image@@UAEXXZ)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_GIF_Image::Fl_GIF_Image(char const *)" (??0Fl_GIF_Image@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Image::Image(struct Point,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,enum Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding)" (??0Image@Graph_lib@@QAE@UPoint@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4Encoding@Suffix@1@@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_JPEG_Image::Fl_JPEG_Image(char const *)" (??0Fl_JPEG_Image@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Image::Image(struct Point,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,enum Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding)" (??0Image@Graph_lib@@QAE@UPoint@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4Encoding@Suffix@1@@Z)
1>Graph.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fl_draw(char const *,int,int)" (?fl_draw@@YAXPBDHH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Text::draw_lines(void)const " (?draw_lines@Text@Graph_lib@@UBEXXZ)
1>GUI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Button::Fl_Button(int,int,int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Button@@QAE@HHHHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Button::attach(class Graph_lib::Window &)" (?attach@Button@Graph_lib@@UAEXAAVWindow@2@@Z)
1>GUI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Fl_Input_::value(char const *)" (?value@Fl_Input_@@QAEHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Graph_lib::Out_box::put(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?put@Out_box@Graph_lib@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>GUI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Input::Fl_Input(int,int,int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Input@@QAE@HHHHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::In_box::attach(class Graph_lib::Window &)" (?attach@In_box@Graph_lib@@UAEXAAVWindow@2@@Z)
1>GUI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Output::Fl_Output(int,int,int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Output@@QAE@HHHHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Out_box::attach(class Graph_lib::Window &)" (?attach@Out_box@Graph_lib@@UAEXAAVWindow@2@@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl Fl::run(void)" (?run@Fl@@SAHXZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl Graph_lib::gui_main(void)" (?gui_main@Graph_lib@@YAHXZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Fl_Group::begin(void)" (?begin@Fl_Group@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::attach(class Graph_lib::Widget &)" (?attach@Window@Graph_lib@@QAEXAAVWidget@2@@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Fl_Group::end(void)" (?end@Fl_Group@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::attach(class Graph_lib::Widget &)" (?attach@Window@Graph_lib@@QAEXAAVWidget@2@@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Fl_Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Fl_Window@@MAEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@Graph_lib@@MAEXXZ)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Window@@QAE@HHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::Window(int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Window@Graph_lib@@QAE@HHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>Window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Fl_Window::Fl_Window(int,int,int,int,char const *)" (??0Fl_Window@@QAE@HHHHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::Window(struct Point,int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Window@Graph_lib@@QAE@UPoint@@HHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\henningd\OneDrive - Spring Grove Area School District\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Gin Graphics 2024\Debug\Gin Graphics 2024.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 32 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Gin Graphics 2024.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild completed at 11:17 AM and took 07.864 seconds ==========
```

I have compiled the FLTK libraries for 1.3.9 using 2022 and have copied the files to the correct directories. I have also tried using vcpkg and I get the same errors.

All of the programs I have tried to compile worked using older versions of visual studio.

Am I missing something? Is there a fix for this that anyone is aware of? Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I don't know the first think about visual studio, but where ever the link settings are, check to make sure it is still set up to link the FLTK library.  These are all linker errors.

Comment: Whatever you added to the `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` setting of the current configuration was not enough. It does not look like you are linking to the libraries you compiled.

Comment: You need to look at the actual link command and analyze its arguments.